# Tensorflow Multiprocessing pickle rlock error when passing in session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created a very simple Tensorflow program to test out multiprocessing (shown below), but I keep getting the error:

TypeError: Can't pickle _thread.Rlock objects

I notice that my below program works perfectly if I don't pass in the tensorflow session, and instead just create it within the test_f2 function, so it must have something to do with passing in Tensorflow sessions in multiprocessing situations.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks so much!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import multiprocessing
def test_f2(x, sess):
    import tensorflow as tf
    a = tf.Variable(x, name='a')
    b = tf.Variable(100, name='b')
    c = tf.multiply(a, b, name='c')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    out = sess.run(c)
    sess.close()
    print("OK: %s" % out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_procs = 2
    procs_list = []
    for i in range(num_procs):
        new_session = tf.Session()
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_f2, args=(i, new_session))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()
        procs_list.append(p)
    for p in procs_list:
        p.join()
```

I'm using Tensorflow-GPU 1.14.0 and Python 3.7.4.

Comment: For starters, move all your imports to the top of the file. Also, what version of tensorflow are you using? `Session` and `global_variables_initializer` are located in `tensorflow.compat.v1` for me (I have v2 installed on python 3.7). Finally, is there anything missing from this code, or is it complete and self contained? I am getting `RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().` and i had to add the import for multiprocessing, which makes me think there might be additional missing code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I edited my post, but it should be reproducible. I'm using Tensorflow-GPU 1.14.0, so I believe some of the methods might be deprecated in Tensorflow-2.x. Also, yes, I just added the multiprocessing import. Other than that, it is all the code I have. Does it still not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, move all of your imports to the top of your file (there is still an import at the top of `test_f2()`.

But the bigger issue is the way this is trying to share a session across multiple different processes. The session is dependent on the memory addressing in the parent process, which the child processes cannot access (`multiprocessing` is true `fork` and `exec` type process spawning, it is not threading and the children do not share memory space). You need to create the session in the child processes, it doesn't work to share the way you have it coded.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight! That does make sense. Is there still a way I can share the session in the parent process with the child process? Or somehow pass it in? Also, did you mean spawn() instead of fork()? According to the documentation here (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process) : fork is when The child process, when it begins, is effectively identical to the parent process. All resources of the parent are inherited by the child process. Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic.

Comment: At some point the Python multiprocessing library runs the standard `fork()` system call as it's usually seen in C. It creates completely separate processes with unique PID's and a new memory space. those child processes do not have access to the parent processes memory space. It's true that the content of the parent's memory gets copied, but that doesn't automatically make the processes identical in every way. The `Session` object that gets copied into the memory space of the child when multiprocessing calls `fork()` is not usable without rebuilding the tensorflow session.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry, but one thing I forgot to mention is that I'm using Windows. According to the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process), it seems Windows uses "spawn" by default? So does that mean the processes each start with a fresh Python interpreter so they won't have access to the Session object?

Comment: Hm so is there really no way of passing a tensorflow session object to a child process? I have a graph that's stored in a tesnorflow session that I'd like for the child process to have access to. I was looking at Python shared types (such as https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes) but it doesn't seem it will work for tensorflow objects.

Comment: Oh wow I'm so sorry, I just realized it was me who accidentally downvoted you when I meant to upvote you. It seems I can only modify my vote when you edit your post. If you'd like to do that, I will change it asap. Very sorry about that.